# Compile-time reversal of parameter-pack expansion

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

In the following class template I want to initalize the member-array `b` with the values of the parameter-pack `vv` in *reverse-oder*!

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
public:
    template<typename... B>
    explicit Test(B... vv) : b{vv...,} // how to initialize member b with pack expansion v... in reverse order
    {
    }
private:
    std::byte b[sizeof(T)];
};
```

I can't imagine how to reverse the parameter-pack expansion in a form, that it is as well usable in an initializer list.

Comment: How about `std::reverse(std::begin(b), std::end(b));` ?

Comment: That is a *runtime* reversal after initialization.

Comment: Else you have to play with `std::index_sequence`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With delegating constructor, you may do something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
    template <std::size_t...Is, typename... B>
    Test(std::index_sequence<Is...>, B&&... vv) :
        b{std::get<sizeof...(Is) - 1 - Is>(std::tie(vv...))...}
    {}

public:
    template<typename... B>
    explicit Test(B... vv) : Test(std::index_sequence_for<B...>{}, vv...) {}
private:
    std::byte b[sizeof(T)];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

given that b is a non static data member, the following more compact version may turn out equivalent once optimized(*):

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
public:
    template<typename... B>
    explicit Test(B... vv){ auto rb = std::rbegin(b); ((*rb++ = vv),...); }
private:
    char b[sizeof(T)];
};
```

(*) unless, Jarod42's solution ends up with the already reversed B's in data section when constexpr...

EDIT: it looks like both trunk clang and gcc are so smart to place the reversed B's in the data section *both* in Jarod42's code and mine !

Comment: Looks a bit simpler than Jarod42 solution but depends on compiler-optimization. Thanks!

Comment: @wimlopaan, technically, both solutions depend on compiler optimization (because b is not constexpr); actually, they turn out producing the same asm as far as I can tell ... that is, no reversal is performed at runtime in neither cases

Comment: @wimlopaan, in fact, std::tie and std::get machinery may actually turns out slower in an hypothetically poorely optimized build. The only way to be sure is to mark Test ctor constexpr and use it to initialize a constexpr object or something equivalent ...